# Problem with introducing arctanh in solving an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

stackexchange! I'm having some trouble finding out how to progress with solving my integral 
$\int\frac{1}{aw^2+bw} dw$. I have read that and wants to show that 
$\int\frac{1}{aw^2+bw} dw = -\frac{2}{b} arctanh(\frac{2aw}{b}+1)$

I have tried my hand at this problem and has come this far:

$\int\frac{1}{aw^2+bw} dw$=$\int \frac{1}{w(aw+b)} dw$

using partial fractions i obtain

=$\int \frac{A}{w}+\frac{B}{aw+b} dw $
Therefore  $\frac{1}{(w(aw+b)}= \frac{A}{w}+\frac{B}{aw+b} $.

Multiplying by $w(aw+b)$ which gives $1=A(aw+b)+Bw=Aaw+Ab+Bw=w(Aa+B)+Ab.$ 
By comparing coefficients, we see that $Aa+B=0$ and $Ab=1$.

Therefore $A=1/b$ so that $Aa+B=\frac{a}{b}+B=0→B=-\frac{a}{b}$.

Therefore the integral becomes $\int \frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{ax+b} dx=\int \frac{1}{bw}-\frac{a}{b(aw+b)} dw= \frac{1}{b} \int \frac{1}{w} dw-\int \frac{a}{b(aw+b)} dw=  \frac{lnǀwǀ}{b}-\frac{1}{b} \int \frac{a}{aw+b}  dw$.

By substituting $u=aw+b$ it is seen that $ \frac{du}{dw}=a→dw=\frac{1}{a} du $ so that $ \frac{lnǀwǀ}{b}-\frac{1}{b} \int \frac{a}{au} du = \frac{lnǀwǀ}{b}-\frac{1}{b} \int \frac{1}{u}  du = \frac{lnǀwǀ}{b}-\frac{lnǀuǀ}{b}+k = \frac{lnǀwǀ}{b}-\frac{lnǀaw+bǀ}{b}+k $ $ = \frac{1}{b} (lnǀwǀ-lnǀaw+bǀ)+k=-\frac{1}{b}(lnǀaw+bǀ-lnǀwǀ).$

If $w≠0$ you get $-\frac{ln|\frac{aw+b}{w}|}{b}+k.$

Now i know that $arctanh(x)= \frac{1}{2} ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ for $ǀxǀ<1$, but i can't seem to use this to show that $-\frac{ln|\frac{aw+b}{w}|}{b}+k=-\frac{2}{b} arctanh(\frac{2aw}{b}+1)$

Do any of you know what to do from here or spot a mistake in my logic so far? Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: You could obtain the result directly by completing the square instead of using partial fractions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i think i got it now :-)
So by completing the square you obtain $\int \frac{1}{ (w\sqrt{a}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}})^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}}dw$ so by setting $u=w\sqrt{a}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}} \to \frac{du}{dw}=\sqrt{a} \to dw=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}du$ This gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int\frac{1}{u^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}}du$ (what happends if $u^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}=0$ though?? )

Taking $-1$ out we get $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{a}}\int\frac{1}{\frac{b^2}{4a}-u^2}du$.
We can drag out another constant and obtain $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{a}(\frac{b^2}{4a})}\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{4a}{b^2}u^2}du$.

Put $z^2=\frac{4a}{b^2}u^2 \to z=\frac{2\sqrt{a}}{b}u \to \frac{dz}{du}=\frac{2\sqrt{a}}{b} \to du=\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}dz = -\frac{\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}}{\sqrt{a}\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int \frac{1}{1-z^2}dz=\frac{-2}{b}\int \frac{1}{1-z^2}dz.$

Therefore we can use partial fractions as $\int \frac{1}{(1+z)(1-z)}dz=\int \frac{A}{1+z}+\frac{B}{1-z}dz=\int \frac{A(1-z)+B(1+z)}{(1+z)(1-z)}dz$ By compareing coefficients we get that $B-A=0$ and $B+A=1 \to B=A=\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore the integral becomes $\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1+z}dz+\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1-z}dz$. By substituting $q=1+z \to dq=dz$ and also $p=1-z \to -dp=dz.$ From the expression $\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{q} dq+\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{p} dp$ you can integrate directly and get $\frac{1}{2}(ln|1+z|-ln|1-z|)+k.$ If $1-z \neq0$ you get $\frac{1}{2} ln|\frac{1+z}{1-z}|+k=arctanh(z)+k.$

Subsituting back we obtain $\frac{-2}{b} \int \frac{1}{1-z^2}dz=\frac{-2}{b}arctanh(z)=\frac{-2}{b}arctanh(\frac{2\sqrt{a}}{b}u)=\frac{-2}{b}arctanh(\frac{2\sqrt{a}}{b}(w\sqrt{a}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}))=\frac{-2}{b}arctanh(\frac{2aw}{b}+1)$

as desired.